# Hashing pattern changes every time the server restarts

Tags: node.js, hash, bcrypt

I have a table where there are two columns: **license** & **activated**.

I am storing the license code, not in plain text but hashed. I am using bcrypt module to generate hash with salt round 10. The problem occurs when I search a license into the database. To search a license, I first generate the hash of the license and then search into the database. It works fine until the server is restarted.

When the server restarts, it generates a different hash string for the same license code. Is there any way to fix this? How can I stop changing the hashing pattern for the same license code everytime the server restarts?

Comment: Why not store the salt with the hash?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is the salt and the way you are using bcrypt.
You are using saltRounds to generate new salt (a random value) hence the hash will always be different.
If use a fixed salt value the hash will be the same. See the example below:

```
        const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
        const saltRounds = 10;
        const myPlaintextPassword = 's0/\/\P4$$w0rD';
        const someOtherPlaintextPassword = 'not_bacon';

        bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds, function(err, salt) {
            console.log('new salt:%s',salt);
            bcrypt.hash(myPlaintextPassword, salt, function(err, hash) {
                // Store hash in your password DB.
                console.log('new hash:%s',hash);
            });
        })
        //first time generated values were below, but each run will generate new values:
        //salt:$2b$10$X4kv7j5ZcG39WgogSl16au
        //hash:$2b$10$X4kv7j5ZcG39WgogSl16aupL0..j8Fmm8Lwgq92uWuM5KyXhE6tpO

        //Generate the same hash value as fixed salt value is used
        salt = '$2b$10$X4kv7j5ZcG39WgogSl16au'
        bcrypt.hash(myPlaintextPassword, salt, function(err, hash) {
            console.log('same value:%s', hash); //hash:$2b$10$X4kv7j5ZcG39WgogSl16aupL0..j8Fmm8Lwgq92uWuM5KyXhE6tpO
        });

        // Test comparison
        hash='$2b$10$X4kv7j5ZcG39WgogSl16aupL0..j8Fmm8Lwgq92uWuM5KyXhE6tpO' //first hash of myPlaintextPassword
        bcrypt.compare(myPlaintextPassword, hash, function(err, res) {
            console.log('Test using the correct password/key - should authenticate');
            if (res === true) {
                console.log('authenticated ');
            } else {
                console.log('NOT authenticated');
            }
        });
        bcrypt.compare(someOtherPlaintextPassword, hash, function(err, res) {
            console.log('Test using an incorrect password/key - should fail authentication');
            if (res === true) {
                console.log('authenticated');
            } else {
            console.log('NOT authenticated');
            }
        });
```

Perhaps use some other value as the primary key (a licence number) and some encrypted value to indicate if it's a valid licence.